# Is there an equivalency between fluctuation and effective degrees of freedom?

Tags: thermodynamics, degrees-of-freedom, non-equilibrium, fluctuation-dissipation

Is it possible to use the [fluctuation-dissipation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem) to introduce a new "fictitious" degree of freedom (d.o.f) for an existing coordinate/d.o.f which fluctuates a lot?

Consider a non equilibrium system with 1 degree of freedom. Is it possible to account fluctuations as a second hidden degree of freedom of the system?